# Is it possible to pause mdadm reshape while growing raid?

Tags: mdadm

I'm using mdadm and I'm running a grow operation on my 3 drive Raid 5 to make it use 4 drives.

I put the backupfile in `/root/md0_grow.bak`.

The reshape is apparently supposed to take 7.5h hours, however i would like to move my computer earlier than that will be finished.

Can i somehow pause the reshape, turn of the computer and the resume it once it has been turned on again?

Answer (score 0):

You can safely shutdown the computer and the process will complete correctly later, but any progress made at the time may be lost, and the entire process is started over.  Or it may resume relatively close to where it left off, I forget which, but it is at least safe to do.